# Why messages are stuck on solace server?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms, solace

I'm using spring DMLC for my application with below settings, i'm facing strange behavior with DMLC that if I send 1000 messages on listener queue only ~1990 reaches to dmlc very quickly and ~10 get stuck on server, on further analysis i found that acknowledgements are not sent back for those 10 that's why i can see them on server, after few minutes acks is sent back but very slowly.

further on this i tried `cacheConsumers=false` in CachingConnectionFactory and everything becomes fine, however this makes frequent bind/unbind to mq server and creates huge consumer objects in jmv, does anyone have any solution how to solve this issue keeping  `cacheConsumers=true` ?

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingjmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="queueDestination" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="queueDestination" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="10-10" />
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="1" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="dbTransactionManager" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="cachingjmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheProducers" value="true" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What is the actual `jmsConnectionFactory`? Also why are you using a `CachingConnectionFactory` and caching on the DMLC? Use the direct `jmsConnectionFactory` and set `cacheLevel` to `3`. Generally in a transactional environment (especially JTA) caching breaks things especially when caching consumers.

Comment: `jmsConnectionFactory` is connectionfactory object provided by solace lib, its doing its work fine, i checked that. If i go with `cacheLevel=3` i can see same problem so though to cache it in `CachingConnectionFactory`. yes seems its breaking my app, is there any solution to make it better ?

Comment: We had issues with caching consumers with the DLMC when using a `transactionManager` so we only cache the session and everything else (producers and consumers) are recreated.

Comment: I see your concurrency configuration is `"10-10"` but you should _never_ cache consumers in the CCF when using variable container concurrency - otherwise when the worker count is decremented, and the consumer is put in the cache, there is nothing fetching from that consumer so the behavior you are seeing is what happens then - the broker thinks the cached consumer is active. DLMC consumers are generally long-lived so you shouldn't see lots of consumer creation.

Comment: Its not recommend to keep cached consumers in DMLC with variable concurrency so i kept it fixed 10-10, i'm also not caching consumers in DMLC but in CCF, however i see kinda same problem you mentioned above, is there a solution to solve it? Is it really having problem with transaction manager as mentioned by @M Deinum? No one put fix on that?

Comment: Can you share how `dbTransactionManager` is configured? I can give this a test if I know the config for `dbTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set cacheConsumer to false on the cachingConnectionFactory and also change the cacheLevel to level 3 (CACHE_CONSUMER) on the DefaultMessageListenerClass. This way, the consumer will be cached at the DMLC level and the issue with stuck messages should be resolved without seeing frequent binds/unbinds.

The cacheConsumer should be set to false and you should have the DefaultMessageListenerClasse control the caching because is preferable to have the listener container handle appropriate caching within it's lifecycle. The following note in the Spring documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) discusses this:

> Note: Don't use Spring's CachingConnectionFactory in combination with
>   dynamic scaling. Ideally, don't use it with a message listener
>   container at all, since it is generally preferable to let the listener
>   container itself handle appropriate caching within its lifecycle.
>   Also, stopping and restarting a listener container will only work with
>   an independent, locally cached Connection - not with an externally
>   cached one.